# MATLAB To Mathematica: How to implement imshow()

Tags: image, matlab

I want to implement the MATLAB [imshow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) function in *Mathematica*.

This is a `DensityPlot[]` from *Mathematica*

> [image: This pic was Densityplot by Mathematica]

And this is `imshow()` image generated by *MATLAB*

> [image: This pic was print by imshow() from Matlab]

As you can see there's a difference between the two plots. I want to obtain smooth transition in *Mathematica* as I can in *MATLAB*.

Comment: `newcolor2 = {RGBColor[0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.2`, 0, 0], 
   RGBColor[0.4`, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.6`, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.8`, 0, 0], 
   RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.2`, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.4`, 0], 
   RGBColor[1, 0.6`, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.8`, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0], 
   RGBColor[1, 1, 0.2`], RGBColor[1, 1, 0.4`], RGBColor[1, 1, 0.6`], 
   RGBColor[1, 1, 0.8`], RGBColor[1, 1, 1]};DensityPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> newcolor2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 300]`

Comment: This is the code of pic1

Comment: The equivalent of `imshow` is `Image`, not `DensityPlot`.  `DensityPlot` calculates a function, `Image` constructs an image form a matrix.

Comment: If you clarify your question a bit or describe your application, I'll update (or remove) my answer.  I'm not sure it answers as it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Blend` gives smooth transition between a list of colors:

```
cf[v_] := Blend[{Black, Red, Yellow, White}, v]
DensityPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> cf, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image: densityplot]

For a clear distinction between some set of contours you can use `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ColorFunction -> cf,
 ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image: contourplot]

If you start out with a matrix of data like you would for imshow you can use `ArrayPlot`:

```
data = Table[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2, 0.02}, {y, -2, 2, 0.02}];
ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> cf, Frame -> False]
```

[image: arrayplot]

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively:

```
newcolor = 
  RGBColor /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {0.2`, 0, 0}, {0.4`, 0, 0}, {0.6`, 0, 0},
  {0.8`, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0.2`, 0}, {1, 0.4`, 0},
  {1, 0.6`, 0}, {1, 0.8`, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0.2`},
  {1, 1, 0.4`}, {1, 1, 0.6`}, {1, 1, 0.8`}, {1, 1, 1}};

dat = With[{y = Range[-2, 2, .04]}, Table[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y}]];
ListDensityPlot[dat, ColorFunction -> (Blend[newcolor, #] &)]


dat = With[{y = Range[-2, 2, .01]}, Table[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y}]];
Colorize[Image[Rescale@dat], ColorFunction -> (Blend[newcolor, #] &)]
```

---

Note:

```
dat1 = Table[ Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2, 0.002}, {y, -2, 2, 0.002}]; // Timing
dat2 = With[{y = Range[-2, 2, .002]},  Table[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y}]]; // Timing
dat1 == dat2
(*
{0.904806, Null}

{0.202801, Null}

True
*)
```

Comment: Nice note regarding vectorization.

Comment: With is better than Table! WA!

Comment: FWIW, `dat3 = Outer[Times, #, #] &@ Exp[-Range[-2, 2, 0.002]^2]` is a bit faster (taking even more advantage of the function at hand).

Answer (score 7):

Your question is a bit confusing to me because `imshow` and `DensityPlot` do different things.  `imshow` will take a matrix of values and show it as an image.  The Mathematica equivalent is `Image`.  `DensityPlot` will take a two-argument *function* and plot it in 2D.

Here's a direct comparison (using MATLink to pass the data to MATLAB, for convenience):

[image: MATLAB-and-Mathematica]

If you need to use an alternative colour scheme, you can map the corresponding function to the data to generate RGB values, and construct the image afterwards:

```
Image@Map[List @@ ColorData["Rainbow"][#] &, data, {2}]
```

**Update:** `Colorize[Image[data], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]` is better (thanks to @chyanog!)

[image]

If the input matrix has a smooth gradation of values, so will the image (provided that the colours scheme is smooth---most of them are).

Comment: Elaine is cuter then Lena. +1

Comment: `Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]` would be more faster.

Comment: Be careful with doing `Colorize[Image[data], ColorFunction->...]` you lose the normalization step: `data = Table[
   100 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2, 0.02}, {y, -2, 2, 0.02}];
Colorize[Image[#], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] & /@ {data, data/Max[data]}` and not even `ColorFunctionScaling->True` will help

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to `simulink` a Gauss beam:

```
 H[m_, x_] := (-1)^m*D[Exp[-x^2], {x, m}];

 Table[ArrayPlot[Table[Evaluate[H[i, x] H[j, y]],
                       {x, -3, 3, .005}, {y, -3, 3, .005}]
                ]
      , {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Gauss beam Simulink]